# Visual Studio for Mac NuGet packages not installing dependencies

Tags: dependencies, nuget, visual-studio-mac

I'm using VS for Mac Community edition and NuGet packages fail to install dependencies.  I have to look at the log to view the missing dependencies, install those first and then install the nuget package I originally wanted.

Anyone have a workaround for this?

Comment: Can you provide more information? How can this be reproduced? What packages are you installing and what is not working? Where are the dependencies? What package sources are you using?

Comment: It was happening on all nuget packages.  Installing them through the command line actually worked for me.  Not sure why it wasn't working using the right click option in VS.